# MUI - How to change the color of each Item in the Pagination component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the background color of each Item in my Pagination component using `makeStyles`.

```js
import { Pagination } from "@material-ui/lab";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const pagination = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "& .Mui-selected": {
      color: "white",
      backgroundColor: "black"
    }
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const paginationClass = pagination();

  return <Pagination count={10} page={10} className={paginationClass.root} />;
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-darkness-wmiwgu?file=/src/App.js:98-116) is a link of what I have currently done.

How can I change the color of each Pagination Item using `makeStyles`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To assign a background color to each item you need to wrap the **Pagination** component and set the **pagination** style (the makeStyles variable) to the wrapper. After that, we can can to handle the list of the pagination elements with the css property `:nth-of-type()`.

###### PS: Starts at the second element, because the first and last are arrows.

```js
import { Pagination } from "@material-ui/lab";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const pagination = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "& li .Mui-selected": {
      color: "white",
      backgroundColor: "black"
    },
    "& li:nth-of-type(2) .Mui-selected": {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    },
    "& li:nth-of-type(3) .Mui-selected": {
      backgroundColor: "green"
    },
    "& li:nth-of-type(4) .Mui-selected": {
      backgroundColor: "orange"
    },
    "& li:nth-of-type(5) .MuiPaginationItem-root": {
      backgroundColor: "violet"
    },
    "& li:nth-of-type(6) .MuiPaginationItem-root": {
      backgroundColor: "magenta"
    }
    ....
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const paginationClass = pagination();

  return (
    <div className={paginationClass.root}>
      <Pagination count={10} page={2} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]

Comment: How do I change the background color for items that are not selected?

Comment: @Meeth46 You need to use `.MuiPaginationItem-root` class instead of `.Mui-selected`. Snipped updated.